# GET OUTER ARRAY KEY BY INNER ARRAY KEY AND VALUE

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key

```
5 Array 

( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 1 [question_id_count] => 3 ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 2 [question_id_count] => 3 ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 3 [question_id_count] => 3 ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 4 [question_id_count] => 5 ) 
  [4] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 5 [question_id_count] => 3 ) 
)
```

Here I need the output 3 ,key -which the `question_id_count` having the value 3

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array, and save the key if the current objects property matches:

```
$outerKey = null;
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($value->question_id == 3){
        $outerKey = $key;
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($outerKey); //int(2)
```